# shell script convert any date to milliseconds

Tags: shell

I want to get this time in milliseconds

```
01/Mar/2012:09:08:00
```

I thought doing the following would store the new date then I can convert the date into milliseconds

```
    time=01/Mar/2012:09:08:00
    newDate=date --set="$time";
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: By "time in milliseconds", do you mean milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01)?  Note that `01/Mar/2012:09:08:00` is not a format recognized by the `date` command.  Can you get the time in a more conventional format like `"01 Mar 2012 09:08:00"`?

Comment: please edit your post to include an example of the desired output. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

You should convert `'01/Mar/2012:09:08:00'` to a valid date string `'01 Mar 2012 09:08:00'`

```
$ time=01/Mar/2012:09:08:00
$ time="${time//// }"
$ time="${time/:/ }"
$ newDate=`date -d "$time" +%s000`
$ echo $newDate
1330564080000
```

Comment: Append `000` for milliseconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bash - does this help you?

`date +%s%N | cut -b1-13`

Ref: https://currentmillis.com/#bash

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timer()` method to get time then put that time in `formatnumber()` method as like

```
FormatNumber(Timer(), 2)
```

Comment: The question was about the Unix shell; the `Timer()` and `FormatNumber()` methods don't exist.

Comment: @KeithThompson This solution is available in VB script or shell scripting sory for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the easiest way to convert date into milliseconds:

```
echo $(date +'%s')
```